# Getting Method Alias to Work

Tags: ruby, delegation

I'm trying 'borrow' some code from the [Ruby Commander Gem](https://github.com/commander-rb/commander). In the example in the Readme, they show a number of method calls that you place in your program like this:

```
require 'commander/import'
program :name, 'Foo Bar'
```

The method program is in the Commander module, Runner class. If you follow the require links you will come to the following module:

```
module Commander
module Delegates
%w(
  add_command
  command
  program
  run!
  global_option
  alias_command
  default_command
  always_trace!
  never_trace!
).each do |meth|
  eval <<-END, binding, __FILE__, __LINE__
    def #{meth}(*args, &block)
      ::Commander::Runner.instance.#{meth}(*args, &block)
    end
  END
end

  def defined_commands(*args, &block)
    ::Commander::Runner.instance.commands(*args, &block)
  end
end
end
```

In the Commander module, Runner class, this is the pertinent code:

```
def self.instance
  @singleton ||= new
end

def program(key, *args, &block)
  if key == :help && !args.empty?
    @program[:help] ||= {}
    @program[:help][args.first] = args.at(1)
  elsif key == :help_formatter && !args.empty?
    @program[key] = (@help_formatter_aliases[args.first] || args.first)
  elsif block
    @program[key] = block
  else
    unless args.empty?
      @program[key] = (args.count == 1 && args[0]) || args
    end
    @program[key]
  end
end
```

I have copied this code into my own program and it doesn't appear to work as I get a method not found error on program. If I instantiate Runner as runner and call runner.program, it works fine.

In my version, which is all in one file, I have

```
module Repel
  class Runner
    # the same methods as above
  end

  module Delegates
    def program(*args, &block)
      ::Repel::Runner.instance.program(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
module Anthematic
  include Repel
  include Repel::Delegates

  #runner = Runner.new
  #runner.program :name, 'Anthematic'

  program :name, 'Anthematic'
  ...
end
```

The error I get is:

> : undefined method `program' for Anthematic:Module (NoMethodError)

The commented out code works when it is uncommented.

How do I get the code to work or, alternatively, is there a better way to do it? I have no idea what's going on in the rest of the eval statement. I'm aware that the number of arguments are off in the program def. I have the same problem with another method where they align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
include Repel::Delegates
```

which [includes](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-include) module methods as instance methods, you should

```
extend Repel::Delegates
```

which will [extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-extend) the class methods.

Comment: That did it. Any idea of what they're trying to do with: eval <<-END, binding, __FILE__, __LINE__
    def #{meth}(*args, &block)
      ::Commander::Runner.instance.#{meth}(*args, &block)
    end
  END

Comment: They delegate these methods. `binding, FILE, LINE` are there just to help a debugger / documentation builder to address these created-on-the-fly methods. [`source_location`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-source_location) etc.